# Верно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

И уже к весне вы сможете скинуть это теплое, уютное, (но, увы, не всегда привлекательное) одеяло.

Comment: Если это школьная работа, сперва напишите свой вариант ответа, а мы поправим, если будет нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Вторая запятая не нужна, так как выражение в скобках является отдельным сообщением второго плана. Его можно просто изъять из предложения.

Answer (score 0):

А я бы убрала запятую после УЮТНОЕ,....

Comment: Да, это дело техники: перед открывающей скобкой знаки препинания не ставятся. Не нужна она,естественно, в данном случае и после закрывающей.